# DataGridView data-bound to a list is not updated

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataGridView databound to BindingSource which is in turn connected to a list of objects. After the data bindings are set up I'm populating the list from the background thread (using Form.Invoke of course). The problem is that the Grid is not updated. I can see in the debugger that the BindingSource contains items and DataGridView is connected to it, but the items are not displayed. What is wrong?

Comment: have you tried forcing the window/grid to be re-drawn after binding?

Comment: Posting some code (like where you are setting up the databinding, etc.) would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Also, do you objects implement the interfaces necessary for data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I need to use BindingList<> instead of List<>.