# Why aren't bound DataGridView cells being updated?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, datagridview

I have successfully bound my DataGridView to a list.  But, the grid doesn't refresh when I programatically change some of the properties of one of the objects within the list.  If I click in the cell (or minimize and then maximize form), the displayed value is refreshed.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143073/datagridview-data-bound-to-a-list-is-not-updated) that I should use a BindingList.  The list I am using is an interface type which doesn't implement IBindingList.  But, the concrete type being used to initialize the list does inherit off of BindingList.  Any ideas?

Comment: what is your platform? WPF? Winforms? Silverlight? (etc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your list must implement `IBindingList` (or be a `BindingList`) and your object must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Both conditions are required for your DataGridView to bind properly.

So if your data source would be, for instance, `MyList<MyClass>`, `MyList` must implement `IBindingList` and `MyClass` must implmenent `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is a neat example: http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/inotifypropertychanged-how-to-and-when.html

Comment: The code I was using was implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and the list was a Binding list.  But, a flag being set was turning off notifications.  This answer helped me figure this out.